# Первые буквы каждого слова строчными

Tags: python

У меня задача сделать первые буквы каждого слова вводимой строки строчными, а остальные заглавными. Например, вводится:

> "СтеНА коВер ПОЛ"

, а нужно получить:

> "сТЕНА кОВЕР пОЛ"

```py
s = input('Введите строку \n')
print(s.replace('т', 'к').replace('Т', 'К').rjust(40))
```

Answer (score 2):

В питоне есть методы для строк. Метод ".title()" переводит первую букву каждого слова в верхний регистр, а остальные в нижний.
Так же есть метод ".swapcase()", который переводит все маленькие буквы в большие, а все большие в маленькие.
Объединив эти 2 метода, мы получим.

```
Пример:
s = 'Волк съел ягоДы'
s = s.title()
print(s)
Волк Съел Ягоды
s = s.swapcase()
print(s)
вОЛК сЪЕЛ яГОДЫ


s = 'Волк съел ягоды'
print(s.title().swapcase())
вОЛК сЪЕЛ яГОДЫ
```

Answer (score 1):

В учебных целаях, думаю можно сделать вот так

```
inputString = 'СтеНА коВер ПОЛ'

letters = inputString.split(' ')
lettersUpd = []
for i in letters:
    letter = ''
    letter += i[0].lower()
    letter += i[1:].upper()
    lettersUpd.append(letter)
print(' '.join(lettersUpd))
```